# Calculate Average Number in a Binary Search Tree

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, average

I want to calculate average . The tree has 4 informations: data,number, left and right. The average for all nodes is = multiply for data and number / total number  .

```
struct node{
int number;
int data;
struct node *right;
struct node *left;  
}
typedef struct node nod;   
typedef struct node* nodePtr;
typedef struct node** nodePtrPtr;
 int main(){
 nodePtr a=NULL;

calAverage(&a);
 }
 void calAverage(nodePtrPtr tree){
 {
   nodePtr g;
   double average, sum=0,num,n,s=0;
   int k,z=0;
    int l,w=0;

   if(tree){
    tree=g;
    g->total_number_of_reviews=k;
    g->scoreNumber=num;
    sum+=(num*k );
    z+=k;
    }


    if(tree->left){
     calAverage(tree->left);        
    }

    if(tree->right){
     calAverage(tree->right);       
    }

average=((sum+s)/(z+w));
printf("%.1lf average ",average);}
```

This code doesnt't work correctly . Do you think I call average method by recursively ?

Comment: 1) member of `struct node right;
struct node left;` --> `*right`, `*left`

Comment: 2) `nodePtr a;calAverage(&a);` : `a` is uninitialize. its not assign value.

Comment: Actually I write these but don't add this page . But My question is about calAverage method --> is it  true ?? @BLUEPIXY

Comment: I seem that way follow the path is not correct. It is easy to understand for the recursive processing.

Comment: Have you got any advice for correct path ? @BLUEPIXY

Comment: use recursive walking.

Comment: OK , I will try it @BLUEPIXY

Comment: I edited my question with recursive methods . But it doesn't work :/ @BLUEPIXY

Comment: Needs to be aggregated.

Comment: Ecxxuse me ,I don't understand you . I think this code  is true but it doesn't work correctly. Please help me. You understand this binary search trees .@BLUEPIXY

Comment: I have posted a sample code for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

sample code

```
struct tree {
    int value;
    struct tree *left;
    struct tree *right;
};

int sum(struct tree *root){
    if(root == NULL)
        return 0;
    return root->value + sum(root->right) + sum(root->left);
}
int count(struct tree *root){
    if(root == NULL)
        return 0;
    return 1 + count(root->right) + count(root->left);
}
double ave(struct tree *root){
    return (double)sum(root) / count(root);
}
void sum_count(struct tree *root, int *sum, int *count){
    if(root != NULL){
        *sum += root->value;
        ++*count;
        sum_count(root->left, sum, count);
        sum_count(root->right, sum, count);
    }
}
double ave2(struct tree *root){
    int sum=0, count=0;
    sum_count(root, &sum, &count);
    return (double)sum / count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do it recursively**

and try this  :

```
struct node{
    int number;
    int data;
    struct node *right;
    struct node *left;  
};


 void calAverage(node *tree)
 {

    node *g;
    double average, sum=0,num,n,s=0;
    int k,z=0;
    int l,w=0;
    g=tree;

    while( g != NULL){
        k=g->number;
        num=g->data;
        sum+=(num*k );
        z+=k;   
        g=g->right;
        while( g != NULL){
            l=g->number;
            n=g->data;
            s+=(n*l);
            w+=l;   
            g= g->left;
        }
    }
    average=((sum+s)/(z+w));
    printf("%.1lf average ",average);
}


int main(int argc)
{
    node *a=NULL;
    calAverage(a);

    scanf("%d");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this by defining two global variable for storing the value of `number*data` and sum of all the data.
then simple recursion

```
s=sumofproduct
p=sumofdata

void average(node *ptr,int *s,int *p)
{
    if(ptr==NULL)
    {
    return ;    
    }
    int k=ptr->data;
    int l=ptr->number;  
    *p=(*p)+k*l;
    *s=*s+ptr->data;    
    if(ptr->left)
    average(ptr->left,s,p);
    if((ptr->right))
    average(ptr->right,s,p);
}
```

then in main I printed sumofproduct / sumofdata